# How to find distinct data in nifi getmongo

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

Am trying to map the below query to run on NiFi `GetMongo`

`db.profile.distinct('domain' ,  { insertionTime: {$gt:new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-15)) } } )`

the runs okey on mongo, but keeps throwing error on NiFi that, it's not a valid extemded JSON

Comment: log from nifi-app.log please

Comment: try caluculating the date and building the query document on a separate lines, and see what is being produced and which is causing the error..

Answer (score 0):

The value for the query attribute in the GetMongo processor must be extended JSON. In other words, it can't contain the "db.collectionName.distinct()" part. It has to be of the form { "key": "value"}.

An alternative to using the GetMongo processor to accomplish this would be to use the RunMongoAggregation processor. You can use the $group operator and use the accumulator $addToSet to get a distinct list of values.

For example,

```
db.foobar.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "foo": { "$addToSet": "$bar"}
        }
}])
```

This will return a Document with the key "foo" and the value of foo will be an array/list with distinct values for the "bar" fields in the "foobar" collection.